# Attempting to print Generic.self in debugger ends the session

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, lldb

Suppose I'm using a generic type like this:

```
class Foo<T> {
    init () {
        print(T.self)
        // Breakpoint here
    }
}

Foo<String>()
```

At first it prints "String" as expected, but then when paused on the breakpoint if I type `po T.self` into the debugger, instead of displaying the result it immediately ends the debugging session. `po String.self` works properly, so I assume it's something specific to generics.

Is this a bug in Xcode? Is there any way to work around it, to see the current type of a generic without having to add extra debugging lines to the code itself?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Prints out `Swift.String` on my machine.

Comment: If you mean by "ends the debugging session" the debugger quits or crashes, that's always a bug.  You don't say what swift version you are using, and resolving swift generics has been a tricky part of the swift-debugger interface.  So this might well be fixed in a more recent swift.  I can't repro this with the Xcode 11 beta.  But regardless, if you have some sample code that reproduces this, please file a bug with either http://bugs.swift.org or http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: @JimIngham Swift 5, but I'm still using Xcode 10.3 so maybe it's fixed in the beta?

Comment: Possibly, we did a lot of work to make type reconstruction more solid in Swift 5.1 (Xcode 11).  I couldn't repro the problem but I only have 11 installed at this point so this may also be some configuration difference.  Not sure what matt was using...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments that can't reproduce it, this might be a problem with my environment or something. However, I was able to avoid it by using `po print(T.self)` instead, so hopefully that should work if anyone else is experiencing the same issue.